# Error : Must declare the table variable "@RestoreList"

Tags: c#, sql

I stuck with this error in my new littre project.

Here the code :

```
                Cmd.Connection = Cnx;
                Cmd.CommandText = "DECLARE @command varchar(5000);";
                Cmd.CommandText = "DECLARE @RestoreList TABLE(DB_name VARCHAR(100), RS_name VARCHAR(100), RS_DateCloture DATETIME);";
                Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @command = 'IF ''?'' IN (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1 AND CASE WHEN state_desc = ''ONLINE'' THEN OBJECT_ID( QUOTENAME( name ) + ''.[dbo].[P_DOSSIER]'',''U'' ) END IS NOT NULL) BEGIN USE [?] SELECT DB_name = CAST(DB_NAME() AS VARCHAR(100)), RS_name = CAST(D_RaisonSoc AS VARCHAR(100)), RS_DateCloture = CAST((SELECT Max(v) FROM (VALUES ([D_FinExo01]), ([D_FinExo02]), ([D_FinExo03]),([D_FinExo04]),([D_FinExo05])) AS value(v)) AS DATETIME) FROM [?].[dbo].[P_DOSSIER] END';";
                Cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO @RestoreList EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command;";
                Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM @RestoreList;";

                SqlDataReader reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

If someone can tell what is wrong ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code is product specific.

Comment: Did you realize that you are replacing for  5 times the command text leaving only the last string as the one executed? Closing as typo

Comment: Yes @Steve. I see that. I have try to right all in an unique CommandText, but something wrong. But how to write something readable with only one ComandText ?

Comment: [C# Verbatim identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cmd.CommandText = @"
DECLARE @command varchar(5000);
-- all your lines here
SELECT * FROM @RestoreList;";
```